# How do I take a user input and print the corresponding key from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, input

Python newbie here, I'm trying to take a dictionary that I've created, ask the program user to input a value between 1 and 4, and print the key-value correspondent in the dictionary I've created in response to the users' input.

```js
names = {1:'Harry',2:'Sally',3:'Joe',4:'Mathew'}

userInput = int(input('give me a value from 1-4: '))

for userInput in names:
    print(names[userInput])
```

This is as far as I've gotten and I've been trying to google the solution to my problem as much as possible but I can't seem to find anything :(. If anyone knows about this could someone explain to me where I'm going wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of your `for` loop?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `print(names[userInput])`, what does that mean? In order to print the desired value from the dictionary, what should `userInput` be equal to at this point in the program? In your own words, where the code says `userInput = int(input('give me a value from 1-4: '))`, what effect does that have on `userInput`? Does that make it equal to what you want? In your own words, where the code says `for userInput in names:`, what does that mean? What will happen to the value of `userInput` as a result? Do you want that to happen? Do you see how to fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I've been trying to google the solution to my problem as much as possible but I can't seem to find anything :(" What specific things did you try searching for? What web pages did you find? What things did you try doing as a result of reading those web pages? Why and how did they not work?

Comment: My advice to you is to try to follow a tutorial start to finish, to make sure you learn the fundamentals. If you have difficulty understanding a tutorial or completing its exercises, it is normally better to try using an actual *discussion forum*, such as Reddit or Quora. This is not a discussion forum, which means we aren't interested in conversational language in questions, and we aren't interested in your frustration with the learning process, or your level of experience. We are interested in specific, clearly-asked questions following the guidelines in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the value in userInput by using the same variable name in the loop. Try as follows

```
names = {1:'Harry',2:'Sally',3:'Joe',4:'Mathew'}

userInput = int(input('give me a value from 1-4: '))

print(names[userInput])
```